# Mongoose, update a nested object inside a nested object

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

i'm trying to update an object that is inside an array that is nested inside an array my schema is the following:

```
const quizzerSchema = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    title: {
      type: String,
    },
    imgUrl: {
      type: String,
    },
    SKU: {
      type: String,
    },
    topics: [
      {
        topicTitle: { type: String },
        questions: [
          {
            section: { type: String },
            setup: { type: String },
            question: { type: String },
            correct: { type: String },
            answer: { type: String },
            note: { type: String },
            questionNumber: { type: String },
            a: { type: String },
            b: { type: String },
            c: { type: String },
            d: { type: String },
            e: { type: String },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);
```

I want to be able to update the values of a specific object that inside the questions array.

I was able to update the object that is inside the topics array, but now I need to go a level deeper

This is how I am updating the first nested level (Object inside topics)

```
 let updateTopic = await Quizzer.findOneAndUpdate(
    { _id: bookid, 'topics._id': topicid },
    {
      $set: {
        'topics.$.topicTitle': topicTitle,
      },
    }
  );
```

But I don't know how to access a level deeper.

Any help would be super appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can update specific nested value using arrayFilters as below:

```
db.collection.update({},
{
 $set: {
"topics.$[x].questions.$[y].d": "New_Value"
}
},
{
 arrayFilters: [
   {
    "x.questions": {
        $exists: true
    }
 },
 {
    "y.c": "2"
 }
 ]
})
```

Explained:

1. Define 2x arrayFilters x & y in the arrayFilter section to identify the nested element
2. Use in the $set part the filters to update the nested field with key "d" in the example

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ht3M1kK3dr5)